# How to easily transform CLI output into a String

Tags: python, arrays, command, command-line-interface, ssid

im trying to get a list of SSID's into Display

After a while I found that the CLI Command im looking for is

```
nm-tool | grep "Infra"  | cut -d " " -f5-7
```

What shows me the SSID's I need, but now I want to create a variable on Python using this output. When I just record it in a variable it turns it into a interger with value 0, but what I want is an array where I can use

ArrayName[0] = First SSID
ArrayName[1] = Second SSID

Comment: try `subprocess.check_output('nm-tool | grep "Infra"  | cut -d " " -f5-7', shell=True)`

Comment: @Avinash Raj, check_output will return a single string value. Not a tuple. You will need to get the string value and then run a str.split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using subprocess.call since you said you are getting an integer return type. Instead you probably want to use subprocess.check_output. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
Use a combination of subprocess.check_output to run the command and then str.split to split the data into an actual list rather than a single string.